# Kendo ui Multiselect validation

Tags: jquery, validation, kendo-ui

does anyone knows how to validate the Kendo UI Multiselect Widget with the Kendo UI validator?
I only want to check if the selections contains something or is empty. 

The Multiselect should be required.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given a multiselect defined as:

```
<select id="tags" multiple="multiple" name="tags" required data-required-msg="Select start time"></select>
```

and the following JavaScript for initializing it:

```
var multi = $("#tags").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function (op) {
                var data = [
                    "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Option5"
                ];
                op.success(data);
            }
        }
    }
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

Add the following code for validating it:

```
// Get reference to the validator
var validator = $("#tags").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

// Bind validation to blur
$("input", multi.wrapper).on("blur", function() {
    validator.validate();
});
```

Comment: I used this answer to fix validation on our multiselects.  The key to the fix was that we were creating the multiselects on `input` elements instead of `select`s which will prevent validation from working correctly: http://plnkr.co/edit/Riu7EjKq0JjxAElmaQ85?p=preview

Comment: As always OnaBai is the Top Man :-)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ej. thank you so much, I spent a bunch of time trying different CSS hacks to get the validation messages to show up properly, and the whole problem was just that I was using <input> instead of <select>. Also had to add <span class="k-invalid-msg" name="element-name"/> to get all the validation messages to show up at the same time. Why the authors of kendo require so many steps to get validation to work is beyond me...